# Waiting for localhost when trying to connect to node js server

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

when i run this , i should be able to get mysite  at localhost:3000 . but when i go to localhost:3000 it is not loading. chrome is still showing waiting for localhost. This is the code . It is a simple node js blog that uses mongo db. I got it from this github https://github.com/pankajwp/node-js-blog

This is the code for server. Please help
i will add my mongodb credentials to mongoose.connect.

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
var expressLayouts = require('express-ejs-layouts');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('');


var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

app.use('/assests',express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.use(expressLayouts);

app.use((req, res, next) => {
        res.locals.baseUrl = req.baseUrl;
     next();
});

// by default express will look for static files inside the filder called views
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');


// Controllers
var pageController = require('./controllers/pageController');
var postController = require('./controllers/postController');
var adminController = require('./controllers/adminController');
var randomController = require('./controllers/randomController');

randomController(app);
adminController(app, Schema, mongoose);
postController(app, Schema, mongoose);
pageController(app, Schema, mongoose);

// Listen
app.listen(port);
console.log('Listening on localhost:'+ port);
```

Comment: please help. It is very urgent. I need to get this working and i am new to node js

Answer (score 0):

Following thing is wrong

```
// Listen
app.listen(port);
console.log('Listening on localhost:'+ port);
```

Right away after calling `listen`, app does not listen immediately to the specified port.

The code should be like following

```
app.listen(port, function() {
    console.log(`Listening on localhost: ${port}!`);
})
```

What is happening here, listening to a port is a asynchronous task. It is accepting some callback to let you know, what is the status of your listening to the port. If successful, then callback is called.

What your code was doing is, whether the listening to port is success of not, it always prints `Listening on localhost: xxxx`.

Example taken from directly [Express Hello world](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/hello-world.html).

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
const express = require('express');
const ejs = require('ejs');
const expressLayouts = require('express-ejs-layouts');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

  //Create Object like this
  const Schema = new mongoose.Schema({
     //your properties name goes here like:
      name: {
         type:String
    }
   });

   app.use('/assests',express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
   app.use(expressLayouts);

    app.use((req, res, next) => {
      res.locals.baseUrl = req.baseUrl;
      next();
     });


   // by default express will look for static files inside the filder called views
     app.set('view engine', 'ejs');


 // Controllers
   var pageController = require('./controllers/pageController');
   var postController = require('./controllers/postController');
   var adminController = require('./controllers/adminController');
   var randomController = require('./controllers/randomController');

    randomController(app);
    adminController(app, Schema, mongoose);
    postController(app, Schema, mongoose);
    pageController(app, Schema, mongoose);

//db connection
  mongoose
    .connect('url goes here, ({useUnifiedTopology: true, useNewUrlParser:true}))
    .then(() => console.log('MongoDB connected!!!'))
    .catch(err => console.log(err));

 app.listen(port, (req, res) => console.log(`Server is running at ${port}`));
```

Comment: ReferenceError: Schema is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\RahulVk\Downloads\node-js-blog\node-js-blog-master\app.js:29:26)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1158:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1178:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1002:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:901:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:74:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:18:47

Comment: Updated!! added Schema Object

Answer (score 0):

you can try with adding this code jsut after declaring your port number.

```
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

your updated code should looks like below and it should work on http://localhost:3000

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.use(bodyParser.json());
var expressLayouts = require('express-ejs-layouts');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('');


var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

app.use('/assests',express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.use(expressLayouts);

app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.locals.baseUrl = req.baseUrl;
 next();
});

// by default express will look for static files inside the filder called views
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');


// Controllers
var pageController = require('./controllers/pageController');
var postController = require('./controllers/postController');
var adminController = require('./controllers/adminController');
var randomController = require('./controllers/randomController');

randomController(app);
adminController(app, Schema, mongoose);
postController(app, Schema, mongoose);
pageController(app, Schema, mongoose);

// Listen
app.listen(port);
console.log('Listening on localhost:'+ port);
```